# How can I use Capifony to deploy a symfony 1.4 project that uses Mongo

Tags: symfony1, mongodb, capistrano

I have a symfony 1.4 project that uses Mongo db, but now I come to set up the deployment tasks with Capifony I can't get deployment to work as Capifony seems to take for granted the fact that I will be working with the databases.yml file, and either Doctrine or Propel - which I'm not in this case.

Is there an easy way to work round this?

I presume if I knew what I was looking for I could remove the bits of the Recipe that try to create the model and set up the databases.yml file for example..?

I'm stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by hacking capifony.rb to remove all the db / orm related stuff.

http://github.com/blinkpete/capifony/tree/master/lib

Would be cool to merge it with the original to make the orm / db assumptions optional, but for now at least it works on my project.